# Difference between putchar(), putch(), fputchar()?

Tags: c

I read these concepts from the book and I searched a lot on internet too but there is no good definition and explanation available. Everywhere it is just written that `putch()`, `putchar()` and `fputchar()` work in the same way and are used to print character to console but I think there must be some different between them ?

Answer (score 7):

[This simple manual page certainly describes the differences](http://linux.die.net/man/3/putchar), albeit tersely:

- `fputc()` writes the character `c`, cast to an `unsigned char`, to stream.
- `putc()` is equivalent to `fputc()` except that it may be implemented as a macro which evaluates stream more than once.
- `putchar(c)` is equivalent to `putc(c, stdout)`.

Comment: And `putch` is a nonstandard function from `conio.h`.

Comment: I don't get the main difference between these three functions ?

Answer (score 1):

From [here](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/putchar/):

```
int fputc(int c, FILE *stream);

int putc(int c, FILE *stream);

int putchar(int c);
```

> The fputc() function writes the character c (converted to an
>   ``unsigned char'') to the output stream pointed to by stream.
>
> The putc() macro acts essentially identically to fputc(), but is a
>   macro that expands in-line.  It may evaluate stream more than once, so
>   arguments given to putc() should not be expressions with potential
>   side effects.
>
> The putchar() function is identical to putc() with an output stream of
>   stdout.

Comment: I don't get the main difference between these three functions ?

Comment: @VikasVerma Doesn't the text I quote explain the differences?

Answer (score 0):

`putch()` comes from standard library `conio.h` and  it is not supported on Linux [As what wiki says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conio.h), it is not defined by C standard.

`putchar()` comes from `stdio.h` and you can use it with no problems on Linux.